# What is the equivalent functionlity of SvgExporter.generate in Ext JS 6.2.0

Tags: svg, extjs6

I'm working on 'up gradation of Ext JS version from 5.0.0 to 6.2.0'. In Extjs 5.0 **'generate( surface, [config] ) : String '** method is used for exports the passed surface to a SVG string representation and returns SVG as a string.

In 6.2.0 what is the **equivalent functionality** for generate?. Please advice on this

Here the details of method:

**Ext.draw.engine.SvgExporter.**

**generate( surface, [config] ) : String**